# Is there a clean way to pass data from a received response to my own response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, proxy

I have a project where one of my Web API action methods wants to effectively act as a proxy to a similar method in another service.

So, we issue a request and create a response:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, remoteUri);
foreach (var mediaType in acceptableTypes)
{
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(mediaType);
}

using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request))
{
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unexpected status: " +
             response.StatusCode.ToString() + " for the resource Uri " +
             resourceUri);
    }

    var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    msg.Content = response.Content;

    return msg;
}
```

But this doesn't work - by the time it actually tries to consume/use the content, it's been `Dispose`d because the `HttpResponseMessage` it arrived on has been `Dispose`d by the `using` statement.

I could take out the `using` but then that doesn't seem clean to leave a `Dispose`able object lurking around.

Everything else I try seems to either leave other `Dispose`able objects lurking around (provided that they're used before a GC sweep causes them to be `Dispose`d anyway), or I have to load everything into e.g. a large `byte[]` and consume lots of memory.

Ideally I'd be using the stream interfaces that are exposed so that I don't have to load all of the content into memory, but I just can't seem to find the correct incantation to use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this doesn't work - by the time it actually tries to consume/use the content, it's been `Dispose`d because the `HttpResponseMessage` it arrived on has been `Dispose`d by the `using` statement.

I am such a numpty at times - yes, the "containing" object has been `Dispose`d and so the content has been `Dispose`d. The clean way to cope with this is to make it no longer be contained by the *received* message. Of course, it's still contained by the message that I'm sending, and it will (appropriately) get cleaned up when that message is.

So the fix is simply:

```
using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request))
{
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unexpected status: " +
             response.StatusCode.ToString() + " for the resource Uri " +
             resourceUri);
    }

    var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    msg.Content = response.Content;

    response.Content = null; //<-- New line here

    return msg;
}
```

---

I swear I didn't have this answer ready when I asked the question. I'd spent 2-3 hours bashing my head against this problem. 10 minutes after asking the question on SO, I now have a fix. Of course, I'll leave this open in case people can come up with better solutions, or just wish to comment on the question or answer.